# Multiple Selenium Grid 2 Test: how to run in Firefox with hidden windows Browser

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-grid2

I would like to run a Selenium Grid 2 Test with 50 parallel Instances of Firefox independent Browsers (or more). But if all these browsers windows open, it requires a lot of machine memory. For this reason I want to run the test with the hidden Firefox windows. How to run this Test with Firefox windows in Background. I tried:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground", true);
capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```

But it did not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: search for running Selenium as **headless mode**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using HTMLUnitDriver.  That will make sure that no UI is launched.  This is the performant and proven way of doing sanity testing.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
driver.get("http://anysiteurl");
driver.quit();
```